# CKeditor custom anchor links list?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I've got many seprate textareas in my own CMS and you can edit this text in an ckeditor when you click on it.

The anchor target is *not* in the text that you edit but somewhere else on the page. How can I pass a list of anchor targets to ckeditor that the user can select?

An idea?